# shared_ptr strange behaviour

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

This the first question I'm doing.
I've searched a lot but couldn't find the answer.
I'm learning the use of smart pointers on c++14 and the compiler is g++ 5.4.
I want to know why is the variable "t" still prints a value when the reassignment of the shared_ptr should destroy that object. As it does in the second example.
Thanks in advance!

```
shared_ptr<string> p = make_shared<string>("test1");
    string& t = *p.get();
    cout<<t<<endl;
    p = make_shared<string>("test2");
    cout<<t<<endl;
    cout<<"Second Example\n";
    string *p1 = new string("test1");
    string& t1 = *p1;
    cout<<t1<<endl;
    delete p1;
    cout<<t1<<endl;
```

Comment: `string& t1 = *p1;` What have you done here?

Comment: `string *p1 = new string("test1");`  - it is almost _never_ necessary or desirable to dynamically allocate a string like this.

Comment: Assigning to t1 the value that p1 is pointing to.

Comment: Is just an example, i want to know the reason why "t" is still holding a value when the pointer is gone.

Comment: _Assigning to t1 the value..._ but `t1` is supposed to be a reference type. The value you assign it is not an address but a value type

Comment: Yes I know, and thats the behaviour that I'm expecting on the first example, too.
But as I said "t" is still holding a value, that is a reference to something that shouldn't exist

Comment: Somewhat related (there must be lots of duplicates for this) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22404296/delete-pointer-does-not-delete-all-the-memory-array And this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34055639/values-still-accessible-after-i-call-delete-c

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896238/dereferencing-deleted-pointers-always-result-in-an-access-violation

Answer (score 4):

> I want to know why is the variable "t" still prints a value when the reassignment of the shared_ptr should destroy that object.

Because the behaviour of accessing destroyed objects is undefined. Possible behaviours include, none of which are guaranteed:

```
 - working
 - not working
 - random output
 - non-random output
 - the expected output
 - unexpected output
 - no output
 - any output
 - crashing at random
 - crashing always
 - not crashing at all
 - corruption of data
 - different behaviour, when executed on another system
 -                    , when compiled with another compiler
 -                    , on tuesday
 -                    , only when you are not looking
 - same behaviour in any or all of the above cases
 - anything else within the power of the computer (hopefully limited by the OS)
```

Comment: You forgot, - working when you use a debugger, - not working when you don't

Comment: Sir, I am stealing your UB list

Comment: you forgot `- ordering pizza`

Comment: Oh now I see, it shouldn't work but it does.
Thanks a lot!
Since I did a lot of tests and in all of them the undifined behaviour was "working".
It was strange that with shared_ptr always worked. Thanks again!

Comment: @JurgenPadilla There is no such requirement that "it shouldn't work". *Nothing* can be expected of the behaviour of the program as far as the standard is concerned.